# Does anyone have older versions of NT and 16s RNA DB from NCBI?

Tags: database, blast, phylogenetics, data-management

I am in search of past years' versions of NT and 16s databases from NCBI.  I recently contacted NCBI about this and they replied:

> Unfortunately, we do not archive past versions of the blast databases. We update them regularly and simply do not have the resources to store older versions.

Any older versions would be OK, but if you happened to have 2012 and 2007 those are preferable.